# Recording When A Record Was Viewed / Visited?

Tags: administration, automation, history-tracking, recentlyviewed

I'm not finding any luck online.

Does anyone know of a way to effectively (considering we're talking about Salesforce within a controlled Corporate environment) **track when a record is VISITED and by WHO?**

Similar to the code used to record the "last Chatter date/time", except this would be the date/time someone literally loaded a record onscreen and viewed it.

*My feeling is that the answer may be something similar to an email "tracking pixel" system... (in that case, when the pixel/graphic is loaded, the server knows it and knows that "email-recipient-x" loaded that graphics, and therefore "saw the email").*

Comment: Do you care about reports, exports, queries, etc? If you just care about views of the detail page you could create a `Visualforce Page` to inject into the `Page Layout`. Otherwise, you'll likely need to pony up for [`Event Monitoring`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm).

Comment: I'm not familiar yet with this Event Monitoring item, but VF seems like a viable possibility now that you bring it up.  I mean, can't a component be made that can be thrown onto a layout,a nd it's purpose is to stamp to two fields NOW() datetime and USERid?  Then you'd have who and when at all times who last looked at the record, yes?

Comment: (and to be clear, I'm desiring actual field data so, yes, reporting, exporting, potentially History tracking)